# How to provide a List/Tuple/Collection to OmegaConf's structured config from Command Line Interface (CLI)?

Tags: python, collections, command-line-interface, omegaconf

I am using `OmegaConf`'s [structured config](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/structured_config.html) system in order to get a convenient, strongly typed way of configuring my Python application, since it takes very few lines of code and allows merging confs from source, filesystem and CLI. This is defined through a `ConfDef` class like the one below.

Now, I want to provide a parameter as a collection of, say, strings. While the `OmegaConf` documentation addresses how should the `ConfDef` look like, no details about the CLI interaction are provided. Hence the question:

### How can we provide a collection of values when calling the Python app from CLI using structured OmegaConf?

I am using Ubuntu20.04, but generic approaches if existing would be preferred.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
from omegaconf import OmegaConf, MISSING


@dataclass
class ConfDef:
    """
    :cvar MY_PATHS: Collection of paths to be processed
    """
    MY_PATHS: List[str] = MISSING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Linux bash, we are expected to provide the collection in the form:

```sh
python my_scripy.py MY_PATHS="[a,b,c]"
```

Then, inside Python, we can instantiate and access the conf e.g. as follows:

```py
conf = OmegaConf.structured(ConfDef())
cli_conf = OmegaConf.from_cli()
conf = OmegaConf.merge(conf, cli_conf)
print("\n\nCONFIGURATION:")
print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(conf), end="\n\n\n")

print(conf.MY_PATHS)  # This prints the list of strings ["a", "b", "c"]
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to expand a `glob` pattern with multiple paths, e.g. `./data/files/*`, this can be achieved as follows:

```sh
# just basenames
python my_script.py MY_PATHS="[`ls -p data/files/ | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','`]"
# absolute paths (nonrecursive)
python my_script.py MY_PATHS="[`EXCEL_PATHS="[`ls -d $PWD/data/files/* | tr '\n' ','`]"`]"
```

Explanation (from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313793/322209)):

- `ls` lists the files in the path
- `grep` flattens the `ls` into a newline-separated list
- `tr`: replaces the newlines with commas

Yielding the collection in the desired form above.

Comment: See also Hydra's docs on use of [quoted values](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/override_grammar/basic/#quoted-values) at the command line.

Comment: I hadn't considered looking at the Hydra docs, thanks a lot!